# How to delete nodes in my binary search tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have created a binary search tree, and am stuck on how to delete a node from my tree. My code currently looks like this:

```
public class Node
{

    public int value;
    public int id;
    public Node left, right;

    public Node(int identifier, int v)
    {
        id = identifier;
        value = v;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

public class BinaryTree
{

    public static Node head;

    public virtual Node insert(Node node,int id, int value)
    {

        if (node == null)
        {
            return (new Node(id, value));
        }
        else
        {
            if (value <= node.value)
            {
                node.left = insert(node.left, id, value);
            }
            else
            {
                node.right = insert(node.right, id, value);
            }
            return node;
        }
    }

    public virtual int maxvalue(Node node)
    {
        Node current = node;

        while (current.right != null)
        {
            current = current.right;
        }
        return (current.id);
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        BinaryTree bt = new BinaryTree();

        Node root = null;
        root = bt.insert(root, 4, 5);
        root = bt.insert(root, 9, 6);
        root = bt.insert(root, 16, 3);
        Console.WriteLine(bt.maxvalue(root));
        root = bt.insert(root, 12, 8);
        Console.WriteLine(bt.maxvalue(root));
        Console.WriteLine(bt.maxvalue(root));
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, every time I print out the id of the node with the highest value, I then want delete that node from my BST. However, I do not know how to implement this function, so if anyone knows how, I would appreciate it.

Comment: what you are looking for is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Comment: It sounds like a homework. If it is - Steve already provided a good link to start. But in case  if it is not you can use an [`OrderedDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: _"am stuck on how to delete a node from my tree"_ -- in what way? What have you tried? What did that code do? How is that different from what you wanted it to do? That said, broadly: to start, you should just get node deletion working (non-trivial for non-leaf nodes in a binary tree), and then it's a simple matter of finding the highest-valued node (trivial) and using the previously-implemented deletion. If this is intended to be done iteratively, you can then move on to optimizing the traversal and deletion together, so that you don't have to restart at the root after each deletion.